# Как получать значение из дата атрибута, которое будет подставляться в объект date?

Tags: javascript, html

есть таймер

в переменной deadline лежит значение
к которой нужно отчитывать время

но если задавать время таким образом, но проблема будет с редактированием
нужно как-то держать их в дата-атрибуте
и потом как-то получать

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      // конечная дата
      const deadline = new Date(2021, 10, 01, 18, 30);
      // id таймера
      let timerId = null;
      // склонение числительных
      function declensionNum(num, words) {
        return words[(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(num % 10 < 5) ? num % 10 : 5]];
      }
      // вычисляем разницу дат и устанавливаем оставшееся времени в качестве содержимого элементов
      function countdownTimer() {
        const diff = deadline - new Date();
        if (diff <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
        }
        const days = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) : 0;
        const hours = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 : 0;
        const minutes = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60 : 0;
        const seconds = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60 : 0;
        $days.textContent = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
        $hours.textContent = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
        $minutes.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        $seconds.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        $days.dataset.title = declensionNum(days, ['день', 'дня', 'дней']);
        $hours.dataset.title = declensionNum(hours, ['час', 'часа', 'часов']);
        $minutes.dataset.title = declensionNum(minutes, ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']);
        $seconds.dataset.title = declensionNum(seconds, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
      }
      // получаем элементы, содержащие компоненты даты
      const $days = document.querySelector('.timer__days');
      const $hours = document.querySelector('.timer__hours');
      const $minutes = document.querySelector('.timer__minutes');
      const $seconds = document.querySelector('.timer__seconds');
      // вызываем функцию countdownTimer
      countdownTimer();
      // вызываем функцию countdownTimer каждую секунду
      timerId = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
    });
```

```css
*,
 *::before,
 *::after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #212529;
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .timer__items {
      display: flex;
      font-size: 48px;
    }

    .timer__item {
      position: relative;
      min-width: 60px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .timer__item::before {
      content: attr(data-title);
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .timer__item:not(:last-child)::after {
      content: ':';
      position: absolute;
      right: -15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="timer" data-time="01.10.2021 18:30">
    <div class="timer__items">
      <div class="timer__item timer__days">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__hours">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__minutes">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__seconds">00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Значения, которые задаются через `data-*` атрибуты доступны через свойство [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) у объекта типа `HTMLElement`:

```
const deadlineStr = document.querySelector('.timer').dataset.time;
```

Далее для получения объекта типа `Date` из строки можно воспользоваться функцией [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), но дата из примера (01.10.2021 18:30) парсится не так, как ожидается: Sun Jan 10 2021 18:30:00 (месяц и день перепутаны).

Поэтому можно либо написать свой парсер для указанного формата даты, либо использовать формат даты, который распарсится методом `Date.parse`, либо как вариант вообще через дата атрибут прокидывать уже timestamp и не делать промежуточный парсинг.

Парсер текущего формата даты мог бы выглядеть так:

```
const parseDate = dateStr => {
   const [date, time] = dateStr.split(' ');
   const [day, month, year] = date.split('.').map(Number);
   const [hours, minutes] = time.split(':').map(Number);
   return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmu5ta8y/)